# VPN-connected Docker container unable to access other containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vpn

I have an application container (app) connected to the internet via a VPN-container (vpn). While that connectivity works, the app container is now unable to connect to the database container (db).

Is there a way to have the `app` container connect to local containers (or any RFC1918 address) while simultaneously also connected through the `vpn`? I would simply add `db` to the same `network_mode` but the `db` very specifically needs to be accessible by another container not connected through the `vpn` (A second application that will read from `db`).

The VPN container is running `bubuntux/nordvpn` and my docker-compose.yml is as follows:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build: app/
    depends_on:
      - db
    network_mode: service:vpn
    depends_on:
      - vpn
  db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    restart: always
    network_mode: service:vpn
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: PASSWORD
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
      POSTGRES_DB: PASSWORD
  vpn:
    image: bubuntux/nordvpn
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2
    devices:
      - /dev/net/tun
    environment:
      - USER=EMAIL@EMAIL.COM
      - "PASS=PASSWORD"
      - CONNECT=United_States
      - TECHNOLOGY=NordLynx
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
```

I have attempted to use `link`, as follows:

```
app:
   links:
      - db
```

However, I get a startup error, specifically that `container type network can't be used with links.`

To restate the question: How do I have a container connected to the internet through a VPN container (In this case bubuntux/nordvpn) that is also accessible by non-VPN connected containers?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When you use `network_mode: service:vpn` in `app`'s config, the `app` and `vpn` services appear to run in the same container network-wise (specifically, they are in the same network namespace). They share interfaces, routing rules, ports, etc. Notably, they also share `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/hosts`. Since `links` just adds a relevant entry to `/etc/hosts`, you can link from `app` to `db` by (counter-intuitively) adding a `db` link to the `vpn` service.

Try the following config:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build: app/
    depends_on:
      - db
    network_mode: service:vpn
  db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    network_mode: bridge
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: USER
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
      POSTGRES_DB: DB
  vpn:
    image: bubuntux/nordvpn
    network_mode: bridge
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2
    devices:
      - /dev/net/tun
    environment:
      - USER=EMAIL@EMAIL.com
      - "PASS=PASSWORD"
      - CONNECT=foo
      - TECHNOLOGY=NordLynx
    links:
      - db # <----- This makes `db` accessible to `app`
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/bubuntux/nordvpn#docker-compose-example-with-web-proxy), this should work:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build: app/
    links:
      - vpn:db     
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    depends_on:
      - vpn
    restart: always
    network_mode: service:vpn
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: PASSWORD
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
      POSTGRES_DB: PASSWORD
  vpn:
    image: bubuntux/nordvpn
    network_mode: bridge 
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2
    devices:
      - /dev/net/tun
    environment:
      - USER=EMAIL@EMAIL.COM
      - "PASS=PASSWORD"
      - CONNECT=United_States
      - TECHNOLOGY=NordLynx
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

You should access the postgres from you machine on localhost:5432

**UPDATE**:

I made this simulation because I don't have access to a paid nordvpn acciut, so vpn service is just an ubuntu sleeping 36000 seconds and the db service is using that network, however this way I don't know what the real vpn service is doing on the host with those added capabilities (NET_ADMIN, SYS_MODULE), but try to give this setup a try.

With this setup app service (that is adminer, a db admin gui) is listening on my machine localhost:8080 and I can login on it and make it connect to the postgres db with the host name db (server name setting on gui) that is listening on its default 5432 postgres port. Also I can reach postgres from my machine localhost:54320 address because it is forwarded to the app service 5432 port that is using the same network as the db service that is using the vpn service network, that would presumably mean using the nordvpn network.

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 54320:5432
    links:
      - vpn:db     
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    depends_on:
      - vpn
    restart: always
    network_mode: service:vpn
    environment:
       - POSTGRES_USER=root
       - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
       - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
  vpn:
    image: ubuntu
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c","echo started && sleep 36000"]
```

Comment: The application `app` is still unable to connect the `db`.

Comment: What is the exact connection error message and what connection string are you using in app to connect to db? For "host" use "db" and for "port" use "5432".

Comment: My connection string is this: `postgres://USER:PASSWORD@db/DATABASENAME`
The error message is `failed to connect to `host=db user=USER database=DATABASENAME`: hostname resolving error (lookup db: Try again)`

The error seems to be related to the hostname lookup.

Comment: The application is still connecting via the local connection (not through the VPN) while the database is still not reachable.

It seems that you are using `network_mode: service:vpn` on the database, which means the database is connected to the VPN. Was this done on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is how `network_mode: service:$name` works:

It creates an implicit dependency from your `app` service to your `vpn` service so `docker-compose` will start the `vpn` container first with its own network namespace and virtual network interfaces connected to a virtual network (in this case the `<project>_default` network created by `docker_compose`).

Then it will start the `app` container *with the same network namespace* as the `vpn` service, i.e. `localhost` in the `vpn` container is the same as `localhost` in the `app` container - so far this is actually what you want.

Now, since you set `network_mode: service:vpn` on the `db` service, too, it will also be added *to the same network namespace* - which is **not** what you want because the container will now not be discoverable as `db` via DNS as it is attached to the network namespace of `vpn` instead of its own.

To achieve what you want you with one of the following:

- First option: remove `network_mode: service:vpn` from `db` so the service will get its own network namespace / internal IP address which can be resolved via DNS - i.e. you can then use "`db`" as the hostname for your database connection
- Second option: use "`localhost`" as the hostname for your database connection since `app` and `db` share the same network namespace, i.e. `localhost` in both refers to the same

For the first option the `docker-compose.yml` would look like this:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build: app/
    depends_on:
      - db
    network_mode: service:vpn
  db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: PASSWORD
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
      POSTGRES_DB: PASSWORD
  vpn:
    image: bubuntux/nordvpn
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2
    devices:
      - /dev/net/tun
    environment:
      - USER=EMAIL@EMAIL.COM
      - "PASS=PASSWORD"
      - CONNECT=United_States
      - TECHNOLOGY=NordLynx
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
```

---

Also note:

- [`links`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#links) is deprecated and shouldn't be used for new applications
- [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on) will ensure that the depended-on services are started before the depending service - but it is not *necessary* for DNS resolution to work, so you could omit it
- you can use [`aliases`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#aliases) if you want to change/assign specific DNS names to a service

For more see [*Networking in Compose*](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

Comment: Putting this together, what would the `docker-compose.yml` file look like? What do I need to change?

Comment: For the first option: just drop `network_mode` from the `db` service, rest of the file stays the same. For the second option: no change to your `docker-compose.yml`, only to your application specific configuration to use `localhost` (or 127.0.0.1) as database host.

Comment: for the first option then the VPN becomes irrelevant as the application container no longer routes through it. my goal is to have the application route through the VPN for all non-local addresses AND be connected to the database.

Comment: No, only the `db` service is affected by this, the `app` service will still have `network_mode: service:vpn` and thus be routed via VPN. If you need your database to be routed through the VPN as well you'll need the second option.

Comment: I updated the answer with the concrete `docker-compose.yml`